# How to display the array value in a table using angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

Following is the Api

```
{
"data": [
  {
      "id": "sdff12",
      "documentTypeId": "617ffgv22",
      "fileType": "TIFF",
      "attributes": [
          {
              "attributeId": "1",
              "customerName": "XYZ",
              "VIN": "10XYAZHSKS"
          },
          {
              "attributeId": "2",
              "customerName": "ABC Dealer",
              "VIN": "98GSBS8S6D"
          }
      ]
  }
]}
```

I need to display the values inside the attribute[] in a normal html table

I want the output as,

```
 **CustName**    |     **VIN**

       xyz       |  10XYAZHSKS

  ABC Dealer     |   98GSBS8S6D
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Use angular material data tables

Comment: Actually I need normal table. How to fetch the value from Api to template

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **`ngFor`** as follows,

```
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>VIN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let dataobj of fetchData.data[0]?.attributes'>
          <td>{{ dataobj.customerName}}</td>
          <td>{{ dataobj.VIN}}</td>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-16sfjc?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually the Api is not called directly in  the component.ts file. I used json server(db.json, eg:http://localhost:3000/data). And In component.ts ,I saved the the api values as   getDetails() {
    this.detailsService
      .getDetails()
      .subscribe(data => { this.fetchData; 
    });......From here I am not able to display the array values in html normal table

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create one **interface** which will have properties like above let me create for you...

create one model named as **data.model.ts**

```
export interface Data {
    id: number;
    documentTpyeId: string;
    fileType: string;
    attributes: Attributes[];

}

export interface Attributes {
    attributeid: number;
    customerName: string;
    vin: string;
}
```

// Now assign your data to one variable in html.component.ts

Data : Data = [];

// Then bind the same to Angular 8 HTML.

// For example :

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th>AttributeId</th>
            <th>CustomerName</th>
            <th>VIN</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor='let item of Data.Attributes'>
                <td>{{item.attributeId}}</td>
                <td>{{item.customerName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.vin}}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need any further discussion

Note: please verify the syntax if something is not working.

Comment: Can you please help me  by using stackblitz??

Comment: did you get the time to check this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here how it is you can iterate and fetch to table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>AttributeId</th>
        <th>CustomerName</th>
        <th>VIN</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData.data[0].attributes">
            <th>{{data.attributeId}}</th>
            <th>{{data.customerName}}</th>
            <th>{{data.VIN}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```